# Memory Leak Issues in Planning Generation Function using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, memory-leaks

I am encountering an issue related to memory leaks while executing a specific PHP function in my WordPress application that generates planning between two dates, and I was hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve this issue.

**Functionality**

The function is designed to fetch and generate planning data based on two MySQL queries and subsequent processing of the results.

**Code**

Here is the part of my code where the memory leaks seems to occurs:

```php
    while ($current_date <= new DateTime($end_date)) {
    
        // Convert the $current_date object to a string.
        // $current_date_string = $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        // Output the $current_date_string variable to the console.
        // debug_to_console('$current_date : ' . $current_date_string);

        if ($current_date->format('N') == $day_of_week) {  // Check if current date is the correct week_day
            
            // debug_to_console('$adjustment[$day_of_week] : ' . $adjustment[$day_of_week]);
            
            
            // Check if $day_of_week is included in $adjust_occurrence and there are remaining skips
            if (isset($adjust_occurrence[$day_of_week]) && $adjustment[$day_of_week] > 0) {
             debug_to_console('$adjustment[$day_of_week] : ' . $adjustment[$day_of_week]);
               $adjustment[$day_of_week]--;  // Decrement the adjustment count
                $current_date->add($interval);
                continue;  // move to the next while loop iteration
            }
            
            if( $current_date < $intervention_date) {
          
                // Move to the next day within the same week if it's not the correct week_day
                $current_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                continue;
            }else {
                  // Register it in the array if it is the relevant day and you don't have to skip
                    $new_repeat = clone $repeat;
                    $new_repeat->intervention_date = $current_date->format('Y-m-d');
                    $repeated_interventions_array[] = $new_repeat;
        
                    // Move to the next occurrence
                    $current_date->add($interval);
            }

          
        } else {
            // Move to the next day within the same week if it's not the correct week_day
            $current_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
    }
}

    // filter modified array 
    // ... your existing code up to the nested foreach loops ...

    
    // Your existing query to fetch modifications
    $modified_repeats = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT *
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}intervention_modification_reference r 
        WHERE r.intervenant_name = %s",
        $intervenant_name
    ));
    // Create a map for quick lookup
    $intervention_map = [];
    foreach ($repeated_interventions_array as $key => $repeated_intervention) {
        $unique_key = $repeated_intervention->intervention_date . $repeated_intervention->start_time . $repeated_intervention->client . $repeated_intervention->intervenant_name;
        $intervention_map[$unique_key] = $key;
    }
    
    // Loop through the modified repeats
    foreach ($modified_repeats as $modified_repeat) {
        $unique_key = $modified_repeat->intervention_date . $modified_repeat->start_time . $modified_repeat->client . $modified_repeat->intervenant_name;
        if (isset($intervention_map[$unique_key])) {
            $key = $intervention_map[$unique_key];
            $repeated_interventions_array[$key]->intervention_date = $modified_repeat->update_intervention_date;
            $repeated_interventions_array[$key]->start_time = $modified_repeat->update_start_time;
            $repeated_interventions_array[$key]->duration_of_mission = $modified_repeat->update_duration_of_mission;
            $repeated_interventions_array[$key]->modification = $modified_repeat->modification;
            $repeated_interventions_array[$key]->mission_achieved = $modified_repeat->mission_achieved;
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

Upon executing this function, memory usage spikes significantly, and the logs indicate that there is a memory leak occurring within this functionality. The function processes two primary MySQL queries, and involves multiple loops, including nested loops, for date calculations and data assignment.

**Specific Concerns**

- The nested loops and date object manipulations could be a potential source of the memory leak.
- Memory management with the fetched MySQL data, especially when manipulating and assigning it to various objects and arrays.
- Optimization and memory usage for DateTime and DateInterval manipulations within loops.

Attempted Solution

In an effort to resolve this issue, I attempted to implement a hashing solution to minimize the complexity of the data lookup operations within the nested loops, hoping it might alleviate the memory leak.

Approach

Using Hash Tables: I introduced hash tables (associative arrays) aiming to reduce the time complexity during lookup operations in the nested loops.

Minimizing Nested Loop: I tried to replace nested loop operations by accessing elements directly using the hash as the key.

Memory Release: Explicitly unset large arrays and variables after their usage, to ensure PHP’s garbage collector deletes them to free up memory.

Here’s a simplified snippet showcasing my approach:

````
```php
$hashTable = [];
foreach ($repeat_results as $repeat) {
    //... [other operations]
    $key = $repeat->intervention_date . '|' . $repeat->start_time;
    $hashTable[$key] = $repeat;
}

foreach ($modified_repeats as $modified_repeat) {
    $key = $modified_repeat->intervention_date . '|' . $modified_repeat->start_time;
    if (isset($hashTable[$key])) {
        // Perform operation
        $hashTable[$key]->intervention_date = $modified_repeat->update_intervention_date;
    

//... [other update operations]
}
}
````

Result

Despite these changes, the memory leak issue persists. While the execution time improved marginally, the function still exhausts PHP memory during larger data operations.

**Questions**

1. Can someone identify any potential sources of memory leaks within this code snippet?
2. Are there best practices for memory management in PHP, especially regarding the MySQL data fetching and processing, which I might be missing or can apply better?
3. How can I optimize the nested loops and date calculations to be more efficient and less memory-intensive?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I appreciate any guidance, advice, or resources that can point me in the right direction to resolve this memory leak issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious things I can see. Firstly

```php
while ($current_date <= new DateTime($end_date)) {
```

creates a new `DateTime` object on every iteration of the while loop (when the condition is tested). Use something like this instead:

```php
$end_datetime = new DateTime($end_date);
while ($current_date <= $end_datetime) {
```

Secondly, you have:

```php
$current_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

in your loop. Each of those causes the creation of a new `DateInterval` object. You should generate that once outside the loop:

```php
$one_day_interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
```

and inside the loop use:

```php
$current_date->add($one_day_interval)
```

Comment: It seems that according to last comment in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70098 the `DateTime` objects leak by desing? Can we assume that `DateInterval` leaks by design, too?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I don't know enough about PHP internals to know if that is true. But I wouldn't say they leak "by design", it's just that the library they use apparently doesn't properly garbage collect.

Comment: I tested the DateTime objects with PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and it seems that they leak about 1 byte per object: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/13759 – not great, not terrible.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Interesting. As you say, not great, but unlikely to cause issues except for long running processes.